# AMP: Group data by category in an array with amp-list

Tags: c#, html, amp-html

I have successfully used `amp-list` and `amp-mustache` to build a list with a simple JSON of an array of objects and have a working version in JS but trying to convert it to AMP. 
I'm trying to *group* it by *category value* of each item. I'm unable to figure out how to make it work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Below is sample codes for the list without the category.

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
<amp-list width="auto" height="140" layout="fixed-height" items="." src="/test-data">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div class="col-12">
            <a href="{{url}}">
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <amp-img src="{{image}}" width="100" height="100"></amp-img>
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <h4>{{text}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Sample JSON Data:

```
[
  {
    "url": "google.com",
    "image": "https://picsum.photos/100",
    "text": "Text Here",
    "category": "A"
  },
  {
    "url": "stackoverflow.com",
    "image": "https://picsum.photos/100",
    "text": "More Text Here",
    "category": "B"
  },
  {
    "url": "yahoo.com",
    "image": "https://picsum.photos/100",
    "text": "Some Text",
    "category": "A"
  },
]
```

Ideal result:

[image]

Comment: I think it's impossible to do that. All that remains is to change the JSON structure by dividing the data into categories.